# The handlebar of the render is not working with POST() method

Tags: javascript, html, express, handlebars.js

I'm  trying to use the hbs with my app, but I got the error when I use post method to render the hbs.
error:
ReferenceError: main is not defined

But when I use get to render other hbs is fine.
Here's my setting.

```
var path = require("path");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
const handle = require("express-handlebars");
app.engine(".hbs",handle({extname:'.hbs', defaultLayout:'main'}));

app.set('view engine','.hbs')
```

and the route function:

```
app.post("/loginvail", function (req, res){
res.render('dashboard', {
      log: log,
      layout: main //It's optional because the defaultlayout is set, but it's not the proble.
    })
}
```

Comment: What are `log` and `main` in your `res.render` call?

Comment: main just the default layout(main.hbs). log is a var like `var log = {email: 'example@email.com'}; `

Comment: You are treating `main` as if it is a local variable, but there is no local variable called `main`, that is why you are getting the error. If it is the name of a layout, it should be a string and wrapped in quotes, as in `'main'`; however, if `'main'` is your default layout, I don't think you need to specify it in your render call.

Comment: But I have another route function `app.get("/", function(req, res){res.render('index' )}) ` and this one can work well with the layout. That's make me confused.

Comment: oh, I see i should quote the main with ''. Thanks for your help